Show $\frac{1}{\ln\left(2\right)}\ln\left(x+1\right)-x^{1+x}<(\arcsin\left(x\right))\cdot\left(1-x\right)$ over $(0,1)$
Problem :
Let $0<x<1$ then we have :
$$\frac{1}{\ln\left(2\right)}\ln\left(x+1\right)-x^{1+x}<(\arcsin\left(x\right))\cdot\left(1-x\right)\tag{I}$$
Some hint :
Making the difference I try to complete the difference using some function and power series as a good numerical estimation is over $x\in (0,1)$:
$$\left(\frac{1}{\ln\left(2\right)}\ln\left(x+1\right)-x^{1+x}\right)-\arcsin\left(x\right)\left(1-x\right)\approx \phi\left(\frac{1}{3}f\left(1-x\right)-\frac{2}{3}\left(1-x\right)^{2}f\left(1-x^{2}\right)\right),f\left(x\right)=-\left(x^{1-x}\ln\left(x\right)\left(1-x-\left(1-\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\right)\right),\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
Then we can use Bernstein's polynomials to make rigorous the approximation .
The hard part is around $x\approx 1^-$ and I look to the derivative I got nothing really pleasant to work with .
On the other hand we have the classical bound as Bernoulli's inequality are not good enought .


Question :


How to show $I$ rigourosly ?

Remark. By Bernoulli inequality, we have $x^x = \frac{x}{x^{1-x}}
\ge \frac{x}{1 + (x - 1)(1-x)} = \frac{1}{2-x}$.
Sketch of a proof.
We split into two cases.
Case 1. $0 < x < 1/3$
Using $\arcsin x \ge x$ and $\ln(1 + x) \le \frac{x}{2}\cdot \frac{2+x}{1+x}$ and $x^x \ge \frac{1}{2-x}$ and $\frac{1}{\ln 2} < \frac{277}{192}$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{277}{192}\cdot \frac{x}{2}\cdot \frac{2+x}{1+x} - \frac{x}{2-x} < (1 - x)x$$
which is true.
Case 2. $1/3 \le x < 1$
We have
$$\frac{1}{\ln{2}}\ln(1 + x) \le 
\frac{237}{61} - \frac{704}{61(3 + x)}, \quad \forall x\in [0, 1].$$
We have
$$x^x \ge \frac{1}{2 - x}, \quad \forall x\in [0, 1].$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{237}{61} - \frac{704}{61(3 + x)}
- \frac{x}{2-x} \le (1-x)\arcsin x,$$
or
$$f(x) := \arcsin x - \frac{\frac{237}{61} - \frac{704}{61(3 + x)}
 - \frac{x}{2-x}}{1 - x} \ge 0.$$
We have, for all $x\in [0, 1)$,
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} - \frac{298x^2 + 28x + 1802}{61(3 + x)^2(2-x)^2} > 0.$$
Also, $f(1/3) = \arcsin\frac13 - \frac{102}{305} > 0$. Thus, $f(x) \ge 0$ on $[1/3, 1)$.
We are done.

Sketch Proof over $(0,1)$:
We have the three bound :
$$g\left(x\right)=\frac{\ln\left(x+1\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}$$ then we have :
$$h\left(x\right)=\frac{3x}{2+x}-x\left(1-x\right)\left(g'\left(1\right)-\frac{2}{3}\right)>g(x)$$
$$x^{1+x}>x\left(1+x-\sqrt{x}\right)^{1+x}>x\left(1+\left(x-\sqrt{x}\right)\left(x+1\right)\right)$$
Then we have :
$$-x\left(1+\left(x-\sqrt{x}\right)\left(x+1\right)\right)+\frac{3x}{2+x}-x\left(1-x\right)\left(g'\left(1\right)-\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{3x\left(1-x\right)}{2+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}<0$$
Where we have used the Shafer Fink inequality, the question "A New bound for Am-Gm"  and a derivative for the first inequality .
Then using a computer we can factor and the remainders finishing proof is let to the reader .
